# Turkish airline Tehran to Chicago flight status

Tags: cancellations, turkish-airlines, covid-19

My mother is coming from Tehran to Chicago (layover at Istanbul) via Turkish Airlines in mid-April. I saw on [the news](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/feb/23/turkey-and-pakistan-close-borders-with-iran-over-coronavirus-deaths) that Turkey is closing its border with Iran due to Coronavirus.

I called Turkish airline number and they said: "there has been no cancellation now but it may change". The representative was very vague.

I am wondering does anyone knows about the situation, I am failing to get a straight answer from the airport officials and airline.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know over and above what the airline has said? No-one can predict what the situation might be in April. There are several questions on TSE on this topic, this one is related to your question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154261/compensation-for-turkish-airlines-cancelling-flight-due-to-corona

Comment: Does anyone have more information? similar experience? knows if flights are still going on from Tehran to Chicago?

Comment: By then it will be different from now. It may be that all flights go again or that all international travel will be stopped, nobody can know now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is completely impossible to know what the situation will be mid-April. We may be in a global pandemic situation with all flights cancelled worldwide, or it may all have died down.

What you can see is the **current** status of flights these days, on [Flightaware](https://flightaware.com/live/findflight?origin=OIIE&destination=LTFM) for instance.

You'll see that at time of writing, it's a mixed bag:

- many recent/upcoming flights have been cancelled
- many recent/current flights are flying or have flown
- many upcoming flights are still scheduled, but that can of course change at any time.

[image]

It looks like Turkish Airlines are the most susceptible to cancelling the flights altogether in this situation, but it's still pretty hard to tell (and things can change in the coming hours).

Right now, it will be completely impossible for you to get a straight answer from anyone, simply because the answer does not exist. Nobody has a crystal ball, nobody knows what will happen in a month and a half.

Answer (score 2):

Turkish airliner has announced this morning (26th Feb.) to re-open their flights coming from Iran from 8th of March as they will have necessary equipment installed at their borders.

This is the latest news, which accordingly it wouldn’t be a problem for your mother’s mid April flight.