# Is there a mandatory quarantine for US citizens travelling from Iran

Tags: international-travel, covid-19

This is a follow up to my [previous question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154330/turkish-airline-tehran-to-chicago-flight-status).

My mother is a US citizen and she is currently stuck in Iran. This is her itinerary for June 12:

```
THY879: IKA -> IST
TK05  : IST -> ORD
```

I had to postpone her flight three times now thankfully without any fee because [THY879 has been canceled since February 28th](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/THY879).

Assuming THY879 resumes before June 12, I am wondering is there a mandatory quarantine that she has to go through or I could simply go pick her up from ORD.

FlightAware status for THY879
[image: FlightAware status for THY879]

Comment: I believe that **at the moment** she would be checked on arrival in the US and possibly told to self-isolate at home. But a lot of things could change between now and June 12th...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can we find frequently updated details about travel/entry restrictions due to Coronavirus (nCoV-19)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/154027/where-can-we-find-frequently-updated-details-about-travel-entry-restrictions-due)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>(Information correct as of May 18th 2020)</sub>

**You mother can enter the US since she is a US citizen.**

From this [Whitehouse article](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/proclamation-suspension-entry-immigrants-nonimmigrants-certain-additional-persons-pose-risk-transmitting-coronavirus/):

> I have determined that it is in the interests of the United States to take action to restrict and suspend the entry into the United States, as immigrants or nonimmigrants, **of all aliens who were physically present within Iran during the 14-day period preceding their entry or attempted entry into the United States.**

As of yet, there is no mandatory quarantine but it is highly recommended and health checks at OCD are in place.

[OCD's website](https://www.flychicago.com/business/media/Pages/Coronavirus.aspx) states:

> The Chicago Department of Aviation (CDA) has no higher priority than the safety and security of the traveling public and our airport community, and we are taking every precaution to keep travelers and employees safe. We are in close contact with our federal and public health partners at the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) and the Chicago Department of Public Health (CDPH), and strictly adhere to their recommendations. We are determined to maintaining normal airport operations, while at the same time supporting CDPH's mandate to reduce the impact of COVID-19 in Chicago.

[CDC's website](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/travelers/faqs.html#International-Travel) states:

> At this time, travel restrictions and entry screening apply only to travelers arriving from some countries or regions with widespread ongoing transmission of COVID-19 **(Iran is one of these countries)**. [Note: US policies are subject to change as the COVID-19 pandemic evolves.]
>
> **You may be screened when you arrive in the United States. After you arrive home, take the following steps to protect yourself and others:**
>
> 1. Stay at home and avoid contact with others. Do not go to work or school.
> 2. Monitor your health. Take your temperature with a thermometer two times a day and monitor for fever. Also watch for cough or trouble breathing.
> 3. Keep your distance from others (about 6 feet or 2 meters) This is referred to as “social distancing.”